# Rasp Pi, pip error setup.py egg_info

Tags: raspbian, python, pip

I am new to pi and I wanted to test it out on a python module for talking to building automation devices. Its called BAC0

From the documentation:
https://bac0.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted.html#where-to-download-the-source-code

I should be able to just do a `pip install BAC0` in terminal on the pi, but when I did this there was an error that popped during the install about ***error setup.py egg_info***

Just for something to try I did a `pip install --upgrade pip` and that seemed to go Ok. But now when I try the `pip install BAC0` again, a new error pops up in the terminal:

***from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main***

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Cheers

***EDIT***

To resolve the issue I ended up just installing berryconda with Python 3.6

See link to download directly into Pi 3 and then run thru the directions:
https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda

Install berryconda to install Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

When pip updates itself its old executable is (kind of) cached, and you need to regenerate it.

All you have to do is close the terminal and reopen it, or run `hash -r` and it will rectify the issue.